# Battery drain on iPhone 12 Pro iOS 16.1.2

Tags: iphone, ios, battery

I recently changed my iPhone XS for an iPhone 12 Pro and I'm loving everything of it except for the overnight battery drainage, which is somewhere between 20% and 30% (didn't see the exact percentage at night and at the morning).

- [This](https://i.imgur.com/CogQYMm.mp4) is what I saw in the morning one day after leaving my phone as I regularly do (no closing apps, no turning off wireless connections, etc...)
- [This](https://i.imgur.com/rObe8Am.mp4) is what I saw after force closing all apps and turning on low power mode
- And finally [this](https://i.imgur.com/gRYPnfS.mp4) is the latest one with airplane mode enabled (all wireless connections disabled)

Things to consider:

- This iPhone was iTunes-restored from the backup of my up-to-date (iOS 16.1.2) older iPhone XS
- No, this is not photo indexing. This is happening for more than a week and my photo gallery is not that big
- This issue didn't happen in my iPhone XS (both have a battery health of 100%)

If you see in the videos, nothing happens overnight, there seems to be "no culprit" yet the battery is draining. I don't consider this normal since my iPhone XS battery chart was flat overnight, maybe down 1%-2%.

**How to diagnose this problem? Is there a way to find what's happening with the battery when there seems to be no app consuming battery during the night period?**

Comment: How much battery did you have in the morning after leaving the iPhone XS overnight without a charger? The iPhone battery life is optimized to be used during a long period daily during a routine.

Comment: I don't recall of noting down the percentage at the night and at the morning, but I distinctly remember waking up in the morning, checking the battery consumption in the last 24 hours and seeing a flat graph, meaning there were almost no energy consumption during the overnight period, as one might expect

Comment: Have you tried to calibrate your battery by letting it run completely to 0% and then straight to 100% without distractions?

Comment: @AkiraTaguchi I'm not very keen on letting my battery discharges completely. Is there any other way to trigger a calibration?

Comment: This is not about triggering a calibration. Any Lithium-ion batteries are generally calibrated like this. You cannot "trigger" a battery calibration because it needs to actually learn how much *you* use your device in order for the OS to learn how much battery would actually be left.